# Not able to cover ngOnInit() in jasmine test case

Tags: angular, angular5, karma-jasmine

I am new to Jasmine for Angular 5.

I am trying to write a test case but in my coverage report I am always getting ngOnInit()t() not covered :
[image]

following is mine spec file, I am passing null to Constructor of my component but in actually it needs a service :

```
  let component: LoginPageHeaderComponent;
          let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginPageHeaderComponent>;

          beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              declarations: [ LoginPageHeaderComponent ],
              providers: [ ServerBindingService  ],
              imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule]
            })
            .compileComponents();

            component = new LoginPageHeaderComponent(null);
          }));
          it('Should initialize all variables ', async(() => {

     component.ngOnInit();
            const a = component.isNetworkCallFinsihed;
            const b = component.allLeftHeaderOptions$;
            const c = component.allRightHeaderOptions$;
            component.ngOnInit();
            fixture.detectChanges();
            expect (a).toBeTruthy() ;
          }));
```

Please let me know what I am missing and I should add here .

**edit**

Adding Component

```
import { ServerBindingService } from './../server-binding.service';
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule   } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@NgModule({
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page-header',
  templateUrl: './login-page-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page-header.component.css']
})
export class LoginPageHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  allLeftHeaderOptions$: Observable<any>;
  allRightHeaderOptions$: Observable<any>;
  isNetworkCallFinsihed: Observable<boolean>;
  constructor(private serverBindingService: ServerBindingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('called');
    this.allLeftHeaderOptions$ = this.serverBindingService.leftHeaderLinks$;
    this.allRightHeaderOptions$ = this.serverBindingService.rightHeaderLinks$;
    this.isNetworkCallFinsihed = this.serverBindingService.isNetworkCallFinished$;
  }

}
```

**Solution** 
I was using fdescribe on my other test case because of this my current test case was not running. Noob error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `ngOnInit()` manually as there is no lifecycle during test. That is intentional.

No lifecycle = No lifecycle hook methods invoked. `ngOnInit` is one of them.

Comment: Just call it: `yourcomponent.ngOnInit()`;

Comment: I called it , but still not able to cover ngOnInit()

Comment: Well, its covered now - even twice nobody knows what for;)

Comment: I tried doing it but still same results, added component now , please check

Comment: Maybe that test is not running. Its obviously covered now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171812/discussion-between-divyanshu-jimmy-and-antoniossss).